# Saving Bitmap to external memory

Tags: java, android, inputstream, gif

i am Saving a GIF into external memory, in my code i am getting the GIF from Drawable and I am able to save it to external memory Fine.But would any one please help me saving GIF from Bitmap of a GifImageView.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        fileName = savedInstanceState.getString("fileName");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gif = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.ggg);
 save.setOnClickListener(new saveclick());
 }


      class saveclick implements Button.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      saveGIF();
                         }
                             }

               private void saveGIF()
{
    try
    {
        File file = new 

          File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                                (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "shared_gif_shai" + 
                  System.currentTimeMillis() +  ".gif");

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


       // InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new 
        FileInputStream("source.bitmap"));
        InputStream is =getResources().openRawResource(+R.drawable.aa);

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //Log.d(TAG, "on do in background, create buffered array output 
        stream");

        byte[] img = new byte[1024];

        int current = 0;


        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baos.write(current);
        }



        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baos.toByteArray());


        fos.flush();

        fos.close();
        is.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

InputStream in this code is getting the GIF from drawable, is there any way to get the bitmap into inputStream? Thanks alot.

Comment: Saving? You are apparently just copying a gif file from drawable to file system. That has nothing to do with bitmaps. Or image views. Or gifs. So why this code?

Comment: @greenapps I was trying to save a GIF from drawable to external memory.. the question is could i save this GIF from GifImageView to external memory ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: I see no gif from gifimageview. I see no gifimageview either. And your code has nothing to do with what you want. Your code only copies a file. That it is a gif file is irrelevant. That code copies any file.

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            fileName = savedInstanceState.getString("fileName");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        si = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ss);

        gif = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.ggg);
  }

this is the full code.

@greenapps

Comment: Please put all code in your post. Not in a comment. Write a decent post. Remove that file copy code. You could as well have posted code to create a database. It has nothing to do with what you want.

Comment: @greenapps did you get what i want to do yet ?